# Re-order active applications in right navigation bar

Tags: unity, launcher

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and I want to know is there a way to re-order the item in my navigation bar. In windows 7 it is possible to group elements and re-order their position.

To be more specific. When I new application is started, it is added in my right navigation bar (or bottom menu for windows).

[image]

Is there a way ti drag the "Chrome" icon for example, and to move it below to Firefox one?
Now, if i try to drag a icon, the all icons move.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Left click and hold on the icon you want to move.

Next drag the icon to the right, so it is pulled off the launcher bar.

Then move the icon up or down to the desired position.

Finally drag the icon left back on to the launcher and let go.